# Precompiled + JIT in the same WebApp

Tags: asp.net

I have a website that is `precompiled`. That leaves the aspx pages and the bin directory to upload to the server. At times I need to make minor changes directly to the files on the server. Such as a spelling correction. If the change is in the aspx files I am able to directly edit the file and change. (no need to build and deploy)

If I have to change a simple event then I can use the aspx page and `<script runat="server">` to specify the changed event (it overrides the once that was precompiled). E.g

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/MySiteSkin.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Article.aspx.cs" Inherits="Mayflower.Website.Article"  %>
<script runat="server">
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //already exists in code behind
    {
       //code....
    }
</script>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphContent" runat="server">
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" CssClass="contactbtn" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

Now what I am trying to do is add a Class to the project which will need frequent code edits and I don't want to do a build and upload each time. This class is also used in other classes so I need to at precompile time too.

I am trying to somehow put a `MyCode.cs` file along with my other project files but that code gets precompiled and I can't override it by adding a newer version of that class on the server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Publish in local and upload only "App_Code.dll" on server

Comment: uploading is the problem.. I want to edit the file directly on the server :(